# Change font family and font size in ActionScript 3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, flash, fonts

I am trying to embed text into Flash using XML and Action Script 3. I found the code that works for me, but I don't know how to change Font and Font Size in Action Script.

Can you help me? Thank you!

My AS3 fie looks like this:

```
var yPlacement:int = 20;
var xPlacement:int = 30;
var distance:int = 60;
var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat(); 
myFormat.color = 0xAA0000; 
myFormat.size = 24; 
myFormat.italic = true; 
myFormat.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER 
var myXML:XML = new XML();
var XML_URL:String = "myXMLFile.xml";
var myXMLURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest(XML_URL);
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(myXMLURL);
myLoader.addEventListener("complete", xmlLoaded);
function xmlLoaded(event:Event):void {
myXML = XML(myLoader.data);
var xmlDoc:XMLDocument = new XMLDocument();
xmlDoc.ignoreWhite = true;
var menuXML:XML = XML(myLoader.data);
xmlDoc.parseXML(menuXML.toXMLString());
for each (var ListItem:XML in myXML..ListItem) {
var listColor:String = ListItem.itemColor.toString();
var listLabel:String = ListItem.itemLabel.toString();
var listPhone:String = ListItem.itemPhone.toString(); 
var myText1:TextField = new TextField();
myText1.text = listLabel;
myText1.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
myText1.x = 2;
myText1.y = 2; 
var myText2:TextField = new TextField();
myText2.text = listPhone;
myText2.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
myText2.x = 2;
myText2.y = 20; 
var clip_mc = new MovieClip();
clip_mc.addChild(myText1);
clip_mc.addChild(myText2);
addChild(clip_mc); 
clip_mc.y = yPlacement; 
clip_mc.x = xPlacement; 
yPlacement = yPlacement + distance; 
}
}
```

And XML File looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<XML>
<myXMLList>
<ListItem>
<itemColor>FFFFFF</itemColor>
<itemLabel>NÃO ACORDES O DRAGÃO</itemLabel>
<itemPhone>SÁBADO - 14H00</itemPhone>
<itemSize>32</itemSize>
</ListItem> 
<ListItem>
<itemColor>FFE8E8</itemColor>
<itemLabel>Emily Owen</itemLabel>
<itemPhone>888-888-8888</itemPhone> 
</ListItem> 
<ListItem>
<itemColor>DDFDB3</itemColor>
<itemLabel>Jeff Jones</itemLabel>
<itemPhone>666-666-6666</itemPhone> 
</ListItem> 
<ListItem>
<itemColor>DDFDB3</itemColor>
<itemLabel>Hello</itemLabel>
<itemPhone>666-666-6666</itemPhone> 
</ListItem>
</myXMLList>
</XML>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found this here, but have not tested:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7d87.html

Theoretically, it would look like this (combining your code and the examples):

```
var myText1:TextField = new TextField();
myText1.text = listLabel;
myText1.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
myText1.x = 2;
myText1.y = 2; 

var format1:TextFormat = new TextFormat(); 
format1.size= 14; 

var format2:TextFormat = new TextFormat(); 
format2.font = "Courier"; 

myText1.setTextFormat(format1); 
myText1.setTextFormat(format2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Each time You change the text, you must call the setTextFormat() method after  You change the text.
Be sure that You have the Font in Your library if You want to embed Fonts :

[image]

[image]

If the text changes and You don't call the setTextFormat(params...)
The TextFormat will be ignored.

Best regards.
Nicolas

Comment: AS3 guide reference : http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/ is nearly clear as PHP Language reference : https://secure.php.net/manual/en/index.php
Even AMO PHP reference is more efficient...

Comment: php.net is full of comments and examples.
On the Adobe website : "Comments have been disabled by the system administrator". S..t :(
On php.net, You may post examples, and so on...
This is sometimes really helpful.

Comment: I think that's a choice made by Adobe to stop support in the future :(
Even if they continue to sell Flash CC.
That's a shame AMO.
They know about the future of flash, even they continue to sell this product!